# pyside2 QTableView clear out model and view

Tags: python, pyside2, qtableview

I created a QTableView and using a QAbstractTableModel for my model.  I want to create a button that will delete the model and clear out everything being shown in the QTableView.  Is there a command to do that?  I was having trouble finding anything in the docs that will remove the model and clear the QTableView.

```
    self.output_list = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    self.output_list.setShowGrid(False)
    self.output_list.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    self.output_list.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.ExtendedSelection)
    self.output_list.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionBehavior.SelectRows)
    self.model = FileTableModel(file_data)
    self.output_list.setModel(self.model)
    self.clear_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Clear table')

class FileTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(FileTableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self.headers = ['File Name', 'Path', 'File Size', 'Modified Date', 'Creation Date']

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

            if isinstance(value, datetime):
                return datetime.strftime(value, "%m/%d/%Y %X %p")
            elif isinstance(value, int):
                return size_conversion(value)
            else:
                return value

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data[0])

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return self.headers[section]
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about the model, this is impossible to answer. Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just create another model and call `setModel()` again.

Comment: Tried setModel(None) and that worked, it cleared everything and cleared everything in the view